# Transparent line appear in the top of rendered image/animation while the viewport is clean

Tags: rendering, lighting, artifacts

this transparent line appeared out of nowhere, I have tried different cameras, it's the same issue, the camera shakify addon is enabled here as well as the motion blur

[image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @YousufChaudhry https://fex.net/s/93xz6tx sorry blend exchange wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be a bug since it doesn't appear on my side. Report it.

However, there is a culprit that can destroy your render:

[image]

Disable this, and it should probably go away. If not, try switching your blender version to the latest or previous version, and then give it a render.